# How to create groupby subplots in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I've got a dataframe with timeseries data of crime with a facet on offence (which looks like the format below). What I'd like to perform a groupby plot on the dataframe so that it's possible to explore trends in crime over time.

```
    Offence                     Rolling year total number of offences       Month
0   Criminal damage and arson   1001                                        2003-03-31
1   Drug offences               66                                         2003-03-31
2   All other theft offences    617                                   2003-03-31
3   Bicycle theft               92                                    2003-03-31
4   Domestic burglary           282                                   2003-03-31
```

I've got some code which does the job, but it's a bit clumsy and it loses the time series formatting that Pandas delivers on a single plot. (I've included an image to illustrate). Can anyone suggest an idiom for such plots that I can use?

I would turn to Seaborn but I can't work out how to format the xlabel as timeseries.

```
subs = []
for idx, (i, g) in enumerate(df.groupby("Offence")):
        subs.append({"data": g.set_index("Month").resample("QS-APR", how="sum").ix["2010":],
                     "title":i})

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(25,15))
for i,g in enumerate(subs):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, i)
    plt.plot(g['data'])
    plt.title(g['title'])
    plt.xlabel("Time")
    plt.ylabel("No. of crimes")
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be interested in a reproducible example of 2x3 scatterplots of oil vs gold prices for 6 consecutive years grouped by years `values.groupby(values.index.year)` in Pandas?

Comment: Definitely. I'm just trying to work through the process...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a reproducible example of 6 scatterplots in Pandas, obtained from `pd.groupby()` for 6 consecutive years. On x axis -- there is oil price (brent) for the year, on y -- the value for sp500 for the same year.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import Quandl as ql
%matplotlib inline

brent = ql.get('FRED/DCOILBRENTEU')
sp500 = ql.get('YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC')
values = pd.DataFrame({'brent':brent.VALUE, 'sp500':sp500.Close}).dropna()["2009":"2015"]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(15,5))
for (year, group), ax in zip(values.groupby(values.index.year), axes.flatten()):
    group.plot(x='brent', y='sp500', kind='scatter', ax=ax, title=year)
```

This produces the below plot:

[image]

(Just in case, from these plots you may infer there was a strong correlation between oil and sp500 in 2010 but not in other years).

You may change `kind` in `group.plot()` so that it suits your specific kind or data. My anticipation, pandas will preserve the date formatting for x-axis if you have it in your data.

Answer (score 2):

[Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) can work great in such cases.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import quandl as ql

df = ql.get(["NSE/OIL.1", "WIKI/AAPL.1"], start_date="2013-1-1")
df.columns = ['OIL', 'AAPL']
df['year'] = df.index.year

from altair import *
```

#### Viz #1- No color by year/No columns by year

```
Chart(df).mark_point(size=1).encode(x='AAPL',y='OIL').configure_cell(width=200, height=150)
```

[image]

#### Viz #2- No color by year/columns by year

```
Chart(df).mark_point(size=1).encode(x='AAPL',y='OIL', column='year').configure_cell(width=140, height=70).configure_facet_cell(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]

#### Viz #3- Color by year

```
Chart(df).mark_point(size=1).encode(x='AAPL',y='OIL', color='year:N').configure_cell(width=140, height=70)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way to plot groups in pandas is actually to [**pivot** the groups into columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (not groupby):

```
table = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Offence', values='Total', aggfunc=sum)

# Offence     Arson  Bicycle  Burglary  Drug  Theft  Violent
# Month                                                     
# 2020-01-31    525      435       303   363    653      762
# 2020-02-29    180      146       438   177    498      381
# 2020-03-31    375      546       421   485    233      277
# ...
# 2021-12-31    329      344       490   550    592      385
```

Pandas can then automatically generate [subplots per column in a given layout](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
table.plot(subplots=True, layout=(3, 2))
```

[image: df.plot subplots]

---

> I would turn to seaborn but I can't work out how to format the xlabel as timeseries.

For seaborn, keep the data in long form without pivoting. Assuming the dates have already been converted [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), format the tick labels using [`autofmt_xdate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate):

```
g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, x='Month', y='Total',
                hue='Offence', col='Offence', estimator=sum,
                col_wrap=2, height=2, aspect=2, legend=False)
g.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image: sns.relplot]