# Subplots with groupby DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have something like the following CSV:

```
date,name,area,score
10/15/2015,john,metallurgy,92
10/16/2015,john,metallurgy,84
10/16/2015,nancy,metallurgy,97
10/17/2015,nancy,metallurgy,76
10/18/2015,john,forestry,81
10/18/2015,john,forestry,46
10/19/2015,nancy,forestry,81
10/19/2015,nancy,forestry,74
10/23/2015,nancy,forestry,83
```

I want to have a plot with subplots for each person (`name`). I want it to look something like this:

[image: plots show here]

Additionally, as showing in the picture, along with plotting the actual score points, I'd like to be able to plot an exponential weighted moving average (ewma) curve, or a series of linear regression lines, etc.

I think I could do it in Python/vanilla matplotlib with something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plots_per_row = 3  # number of columns
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# get number of plots
nplots = 0
by_name_and_area = {}
nplots_by_name = {}
nrows_by_name = {}

for name, namerows in df.groupby(['name']):
    by_name_and_area[name] = {}
    nplots_by_name[name] = 0

    for area, rows in namerows.groupby(['area']):
        by_name_and_area[name][area] = rows['score']
        nplots_by_name[name] += 1

    # decide number of rows
    nrows_by_name[name] = int(nplots / plots_per_row)
    if nplots % plots_per_row > 0:
        nrows_by_name[name] += 1

    # create figure & subplots and iterate through to plot each
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, plots_per_row, sharex=True, sharey=True,  squeeze=True)
    # ... etc, etc
```

but I'd rather do it in `pandas` since I'm trying to learn that and usually Wes has thought through everything before most of us mortals have.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please see if my answer to a similar question [How to create groupby subplots in Pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150510/how-to-create-groupby-subplots-in-pandas/33152131#33152131) helps you