# how to use pandas.groupby.plot to plot scatter plot, with each group in a subplot

Tags: pandas, plot, group-by

I'm not looking for an alternative. I just want to make below code work, because it's a lot simple than otehr solutions.

I want to perform a groupby (A ,B), then scatter plot the relationship for C and D. I want each group is plotted in a subplot. I checked the docs:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html
It seems to be able to do this in one line. However, the code below plot each group seperately in a new chart.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C': np.random.randn(8),
                   'D': np.random.randn(8)})
test.groupby(['A', 'B']).plot(kind='scatter', x='C', y='D', subplots=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293028/plotting-grouped-data-in-same-plot-using-pandas

Comment: Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150510/how-to-create-groupby-subplots-in-pandas ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This is not what I want. Please open the post again. I want each groupby result plot in a subplot instead of all in one.

Comment: @Dark my question is more about why the above code does not work as expected, I'm not asking for an alternative. thank you.

Comment: Please clarify in your post what it is you're trying to solve!